# Curious about proper html structure for paragraphs and various text

Tags: html, css, tags, format, structure

So I've been working on my website for the past few weeks having started off with no understanding of HTML/CSS or JS. In two weeks i managed to learn enough that now I am actually custom coding websites for family and friends who's websites are horribly outdated and look like something from the dial up era.

With regards to my own website...

(which right now I am using a online site editor to speed up the process as I don't have much time to spare for now, I fully plan to rebuild it from scratch when I have the time but just needed something working for now.)

I have been doing a large amount of custom coding to make my site work and was curious about what the structure I should be using for my paragraph and text sections should be. Both for "in-editor" and for "from-scratch-development".

While I 'could' just use the editor's built in *paragraph* tool, I prefer to use the HTML element to get exactly the style I desire. I was wondering on what format I should use to create my paragraph layout as I am stuck on two possible formats to use. I would like to know which I should focus on to give better quality HTML format and to avoid bad habits.

I know that often the `<h#>` tags should be used for titles and important text and the `<p>` tags should be used for anything inside a large paragraph, but because of the default formatting of the editor & that of the browsers, I wanted to know if there is anything wrong with using the "`< div >`" tag option or if its improper somehow and I should use the "`< p >`" tag option.

---

```
< div class="some-header" >
<br>
Some Page Header
<br>
< /div >
<br>
<br>
< div class="some-paragraph" >
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Ut dignissim, tortor id fringilla tincidunt, mauris.
<br>
< /div >
_____________________________________________________
< h1 class="some-header" >
<br>
Some Page Header
<br>
< /h1 >
<br>
<br>
< p class="some-paragraph" >
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Ut dignissim, tortor id fringilla tincidunt, mauris.
<br>
< /p >
_________
```

---

So is there anything wrong with these options? Im really not sure if it even matters. If its just simply trivial semantics and doesn't really have any real impact. Also it should be noted that I tend to stuff my HTML and CSS full of little notes for myself (and anyone else that reads it) just so I don't get lost. Pretty much every single section of code is made all "pretty" with big block comments in fancy boxes and commented titles on EVERYTHING to help me remember what everything is. Any feedback or ideas on the matter are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using **div** elements to encase text content and then using **classes** and **ids** to manipulate them. It is good practice however, to use appropriate elements provided in HTML for specific tasks.

For example, one can make a table out of div elements, but there is no reason to do so as there is already a structure available within HTML for that task. The Document Object Model, is what defines the logical structure of your page and it is good practice to keep the logical structure, logical.

I would suggest using the latter option with the p tags for your paragraph content.

I would also advice against using **br** tags in your code. You can separate your divs using margins instead. If you require one element to be spaced out a little more then all the other elements of the same class use an id.

Cheers!

Comment: i dont suppose you would know (or know where i can find) how to create subpages within subpages.. for example

i have my master page with my header and footer. and theres a page called careers. on the careers page theres a sidebar on the left with a menu and the right 80% of the screen gives the information for the careers listed in the menu on the left..  Kind of like this...
__________________
|_________________|
|       ____________   |
|===| ~~~~~~           |  |
|===|~~~~~~~~~~~~|  |
|===|~~~~~~~~~~~~|  |
|      |~~~~~~~~~~~~|  |
|      |____________|  |
|_________________|

Comment: For sub-sub pages there apparently is a workaround:

https://www.wix.com/support/html5/ticket/9fcd875b-9293-477d-839f-02eb7cadc669

Comment: crap.. ok nvm that didnt line up the way i thought it would.. here ill link a picture.

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/yajo_SiOBP1eV-LGizFR6hp1rbtQnLtCy1zfpiCxgyBnslX04DkA2jZ2dfcQxAYlhOYbsl1Twr-tIT8=w1358-h702-rw

heres a snip from my website.

also. ya that wix.com support ticket thing.. im not using wix.. ironically i used to be actually.. but i needed to start over from scratch and take up custom coding for this project.

Comment: Oh I see. I was just viewing what I found as the first search result for Trigger Game Studios as reference. When you say from scratch ... do you mean that you will be doing all of your html, css, php and javacript from scratch? Not using any frameworks, content management systems or libraries to assist you with the development process? What will your stack be exactly?

Comment: eventually yes. the issue i ran into with WIX as pretty as it was, was the slow loading times, and more than anything.. lack of responsive design for mobile devices.  while there is a "mobile" version tool for wix.. it still wouldnt look right even on desktops because of two factors.. one is fixed site resolution and secondly is my current monitor is a piece of shit at 1360x768. *ughhh... eww*... anyways yes i plan to do it all from scratch soon (as in sometime in the next year). Part of the reason for this is i need to have true 100% custom design and layout for a webstore, forum...

Comment: ... personal profiles.. etc... take a look at something like http://bungie.net and you can get a really good idea of what the bar is for what im trying to accomplish with my website. and the fact that my studio focuses on more than just one game or the development of our own games, but rather also focuses on the production of youtube and twitch game entertainment, game mods, game and studio merchandise, and the support for a full bustling community environment.. the custom coding is going to be very necessary.

Comment: Making everything from scratch sounds like a great learning opportunity, but it is very difficult and time consuming.

Here is a sample tutorial for building your own forum from scratch:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch--net-10188

As you can see you will have to learn quite a bit to properly build and implement a forum in your website.

I suggest you use a Content management system such as WordPress for all of your functionality and then design on top of it. What you can look into is WordPress templates.

Comment: ya. i thought about word press.. and i would totally love if i can find a system like wordpress that gives me everything i need. the only hang ups come with needing things like customization member profiles than can be linked to your accounts on stuff like XBL, PSN, Steam, etc. as well as a full user content sharing system.. also a requirement is the ability to custom design every last visual detail on the site.. like the header, footer.. etc.. (i havnt really looked into wordpress at all) if you happen to have any suggestions that might work for me id love to hear them. ill look into wordpres

Comment: With WordPress you can completely customize your website design wise, and there is a ton of functionality that can be implemented using WordPress widgets.

Here are a few examples of websites made using WordPress.
https://www.nimbusthemes.com/best-wordpress-gaming-themes/